# Eclipse / Aptana - exclude folder from 'Connections' sync

Tags: eclipse, aptana, synchronization

I have a PHP project in Eclipse (with the Aptana Plug-in) that I deploy to a number of different hosts using the 'Connections' Sync mechanism.  The problem is that in addtion to all the common code each site's 'instance' of the project contains a host specific folder tree that can contain a large number of files.  Each time I run 'sync' I have to manually check 'skip' for the host specific folder and all of its children.

Is there any way I can config sync to ignore this folder?

I've looked through the include/exclude filter stuff and various entries in Stackoverflow for 'exclude files/folders' but they all seem to relate only to repository syncs (GIT/SVN ...),  validators, builders etc

jon

Answer (score 2):

I hope this functionality exists in Eclipse with the Aptana Plug-in, I am using Aptana standalone.

I think the option you are looking for is called cloaking. You can set up name patterns for cloaking under Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Publishing. Here you can add file naming patterns to be excluded from all publishing - other projects will also ignore these file name patterns so use caution. I prefix files and folders with an underscore when I don't want them syncing and then just use `_*` in this preference.

Comment: Thx for pointer.
Unfortunately I can't try your suggestion yet because I'm now blocked by a (known) bug in Eclipse 4.2 with the Aptana plugin which breaks the 'Publish' functionality..... and I've just discovered that the published patch simply crashes, so the investigation continues. :-(

Comment: I hope when the bug is resolved you will come back and let us know if this works in Eclipse too :)